# How can I save the results of my web scraping to a text file in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, save, file-handling

I tried to write this code for some web scraping. The code works fine, but I still have trouble figuring out how I can save the results of my web scraping into a .txt file? I want to write the result of "print(div.text)" output into a .txt file.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

for pg in range(1, 100 + 1):
    source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/hayyim_query.py?page='+ str(pg)).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='hw_result'):
        print(div.text)
```

Comment: Open a file for writing, and then instead of calling `print()`, use `myfile.write()` instead.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: how about the format and name of the file?

Should I open the file before the loop?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Text files have no specific format, and you can name a file whatever you like.  Yes, open the file before the loop.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, with `f.open`, `f.write` and `f.close`:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import re

output = ''
for pg in range(1, 100 + 1):
    source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/hayyim_query.py?page='+ str(pg)).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='hw_result'):
        output += div.text

output = re.sub(r"[\r\n]+", "", output)

f = open('/any/directory_you_like/any_name_that_you_like_with_any_extension.txt', 'w')
try:
    f.write(output)
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. The code works. But there are lots of empty lines that are unnecessary. Is there any way to remove the empty lines while the code is being run?

Answer (score 0):

Open a file before the loop

```
file = open(“testfile.txt”, “w”)
```

First argument is the file name and the second means that you want to write in this file

And then instead of `print(div.text)` you should use `file.write(div.text)`

Close the file after the loop with `file.close()`

After all your code should be like this:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
file = open(“testfile.txt”, “w”)
for pg in range(1, 100 + 1):
    source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/hayyim_query.py?page='+ str(pg)).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='hw_result'):
        file.write(div.text) 
file.close()
```